# how does tcp_rmem sysctl affect RAM usage?

Tags: networking, tcp, buffer, throughput

I want to configure tcp_rmem in such way that it works for low latency and high latency both. And at the same time it doesn't consume more memory for the low latency use cases.
Is it possible to achieve that?
I was thinking of setting higher values for tcp_rmem so it works for high latency. 
Imagine if latency is low, then how much memory does every connection allocate for receive buffer?

e.g if I set tcp_rmem to 1MB(min) 2MB(default) 3MB(max).
1. Does it always allocate 2MB per connection, or based on need it allocates 2MB?
2. Does it start with 1MB and when sees that 1MB is not enough, then allocates 2MB and when sees that 2MB is not enough then allocates 3MB.
3. Regardless of latency, it will always allocate 1MB or 2MB or 3MB based on incoming rate?

So in my tests, rate is const and latency is variable. 90% of the times latency is going to be really low. But to handle those 10% of high latency cases, I have to change the tcp_rmem to high value and that impacts 90% other scenarios as well.

I couldn't find how tcp_moderate_rcvbuf parameter works? Based on what parameters memory is allocated.

Comment: Min is the minimum you can set with SO_RCVBUF and Max is the maximum. Default is what you get by default. Not affected by latency, which isn't known at the point of allocation. You don't need to set it higher than the bandwidth-delay product.

Comment: Thanks, I was under impression that window is changed dynamically from min to default and to max based on throughput during runtime. So my understanding was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

min,default,max fields of systcl tcp_rmem and tcp_wmem has following meaning.
min: Its always guaranteed that min amount of socket buffer size would be allocated.
Using socket option SO_RCVBUF, any size can be for receive buffer. But it cannot exceed max.

default: This is total amount of socket buffer size allocated by default.
max: if explicitly set using SO_RCVBUF, one cannot set socket buffer size more than this.

SO if higher values of min, default, max are set. They are always used regardless of the latency and throughput.